# How to make the code runs faster in Python (multiple nested for loops efficiency)

Tags: python, algorithm, nested-loops

I have some codes here that I want to know if there's a way to make the code run better and take less time... I use multiple nested loops here and I don't really know how to improve this piece of code, so thanks for any help that you guys shared down here :)

```
from time import time

def mult_comb(combinations: list[tuple], T: list) -> None:
    for x in range(len(combinations)):
        for _ in range(len(T)):
            for j in range(len(T)):
                combinations.append(combinations[x] + (T[j], ))

def all_possible_combinations(T: list, r: int) -> list:
    combinations: list = []

    for i in range(len(T)):
        for j in range(len(T)): combinations.append((T[i], T[j]))

    for _ in range(r - 2): mult_comb(combinations, T)

    combs_result: set = set(combinations)
    final_combs_result = sorted(combs_result)
    return final_combs_result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start: float = time()
    n, k = ['N', 'P'], 12

    data: list = all_possible_combinations(n, k)    
    print(data)
    print(f"The runtime took: {time() - start:.3f}s")
```

So, this code simply takes probability things, like this example...
"One coin consists of two main body parts, showing the number of the coin and the picture of the coin (`N` represents the number, and `P` represents the picture). If I have 3 coins, then what's the probability of the coins of the samples?" (Sorry for my bad English...)

Basically, the answer is just: `NN, NP, PN, PP, NNN, NNP, NPN, NPP, PNN, PNP, PPN, PPP`.

The code already outputs the correct answer, but when I give the `k` value to `12`, the code runs for about`81.933s`, which is took so much time considering this code only does simple things that our brain can even do this faster... Is there any ways to improve those nested loops? Thank you once again...

Comment: if I understand correctly, you may want to look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), especially "Combinatoric iterators". Why write it yourself, when it is done already :)

Comment: You can consider 1) Use `permutations` class from `itertools` instead. 2) Use list comprehension instead of pure python loop. 3) Unwind the loops - this would mean changing the algorithm

Comment: Why is `NN, NP, PN, PP` in your 3 coins example ?

Comment: @AloisChristen Well, basically it's a full series, starting from the k = 2 to the next one until the given k...

Comment: @VytenisKajackas Thanks for the info, I'm just looking for myself to learn this such new things, maybe like wanting to experiment how such this combinatoric iterators work in the first place... :)

Comment: And why do you need all the possibilities ? There is no probability than 3 coins lands on `NN`

Comment: @yoonghm Thanks for the suggestions, bro... Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @AloisChristen Thanks for the corrections, maybe I forget to delete it before going to the next 3 coins lands... I'm new to this permutation and combination, so I may say sorry if some of this stuffs gets confusing for me... :0

Answer (score 3):

you can create permutations like this

```
l = ['N', 'P']
k = 12

def perm(l, k):
    n, p = l
    res = ['N', 'P']
    prev_gen = (i for i in res)
    for i in range(1, k+1):
        res = (f'{j}{i}' for i in prev_gen for j in (n, p))
        prev_gen = res
    return res
print(list(perm(l,k)))
```